# JSlider freezes program

Tags: java, swing, communication

I currently am developing a program that will send a value between 100 and 355 to a serial port with an Arduino connected with rgb led strips.

The program works fine for a little bit but then suddenly freezes and I cannot move any sliders or click on any of the buttons.

I believe this is due to the program processing too many events because if I move the sliders slowly this problem does not happen as frequently but I do not know how to decrease the amount of events activated by the slider.

Here is My Code for a slider:

```
redslide.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        try {
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int brightness = redslide.getValue();
        String message = "r" + brightness;
        byte[] data = message.getBytes();
        try {
            output.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

here Is my new code:

```
redslide.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        int brightness = redslide.getValue();
        String message = "r" + brightness;
        byte[] data = message.getBytes();
        new Thread(() -> Write(data)).start();
    }
});

public static void Write(byte[] data){
        try {
            output.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sending data is likely not causing the freeze. Is the application also *receiving* data on the Swing event thread?

Comment: ............................hello??

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say for sure without your full program, but it appears you are reading and writing data from the `ChangeListener`.

The read and write operation block for an indeterminate amount of time, during which the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) cannot process additional events.  Blocking the EDT will make your GUI appear to be frozen.

Try spinning off another thread to handle the read/write operation or use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to avoid blocking the EDT.

(Update your post with the a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll try to give you some more specific guidance)

Comment: i would add: If you need to determine whether your code is running on the event dispatch thread, invoke javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread.